vs code some portion are not clickable in ubuntu
Some areas are not clickable when I maximize my vs-code window.
It's working properly when window size is small like that.
small screen 
But main problem comes when maximizing the window full screen or bigger than this size. Mainly not working bottom and right side.
Big screen
VsCode version : 1.89.1
OS : Ubuntu 24.04 LTS

I think that's a topic for a bug report, have you checked their bug tracker?

That sounds more like a window manager problem, most likely related to scaling.

Welcome back to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, so what's the question? We don't take bug reports if that's what you wanted. For tips, see [ask].
